# Thymeleaf expression for Javascript URL using th:href

Tags: thymeleaf

I have lines like the following

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:getSearch('Deelnemer', 'asMemberSearch')">Zoekscherm deelnemers</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:getSearch('Reglement', 'asPlanSearch')">Zoekscherm reglementen</a>
    ...
</div>
```

I would like to generalize that into something like the following lines:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
  <a th:each="anchor : ${anchorList}" 
     th:text="${anchor.title}" 
     th:href="@{/searchCriteria/Search(anchor.object=${anchor.object})}"
     class="dropdown-item"
     href="javascript:getSearch('Deelnemer', 'asMemberSearch')">dummy</a>
</div>
```

However, I cannot see a way to put something after the **th:href** that allows me to have Javascript in there. I have tried `th:href="@{/javascript:getSearch(anchor.object, anchor.search)}"` but that delivers `javascript:getSearch?anchor.object&anchor.search` while what I want is `javascript:getSearch('Deelnemer','asMemberSearch')`. Documentation is [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls).

Answer (score 0):

Your using the `@` notation where you don't want it. `@` is for urls relative to the context path. In your case you'r better of just using strings and `$`. for example `th:href="'javascript:getSearch(\'' + ${anchor.object} + ', ' + ${anchor.search} + '\')'"`